# acces docker containers by ip vs port expose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wildfly

I do have a DOCKER_HOST specified by :

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://g3-docker-1:2375
```

secured by TLS. On this *host* I could have quite a view "jboss/wildfly" containers in different configurations and loaded with different apps. They can be started on request by some people for software testing purposes. The following docker-compose is used :

```
version: '2'
services:

    wildfly:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.wildfly
            context: .
        ports:
                - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
            - logvolume
            - mariadb
        volumes_from:
            - logvolume

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:latest
        ports:
            - "3307:3307"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret

    logvolume:
        build: 
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.logvolume
          context: .
        volumes:
            - /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log
```

I am planning to build quite a view containers each one with different preloaded data and different webapps inside "wildfly"

When I start these containers each one is assigned a IP addres inside the `_dirname_default` network (bridged). Jboss is reachable by the **outside world** with $DOCKER_HOST:8080 and maria_db is reachable so fine so good ...
 But what if I have a couple of this. Do I have to map different ports to the different wildflys or is there another way to access the dockerized wildflys by the **outside** eg. via the containerid or so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now using nginx as reverse proxy in order to decide based on the url which wildfly to talk to

This needs an addtional service in docker-compose.yml like this :

```
reverseproxy:
    build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
        context: .
    ports:
        - 80:80
    depends_on:
        - wildfly
```

and the following nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {
    sendfile on;
    upstream docker-wildfly {
        server wildfly:8080;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        location /wildfly/ {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-wildfly/;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
```

}

Each wildfly will get its own location